# SharePoint 2019 setting up an app management server with a single cert

Tags: ssl, certificate, sharepoint-administration

I am setting up server to host our apps on for SharePoint 2019 on prem. According to this [document provided by Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-an-environment-for-apps-for-sharepoint), you need to provide a wildcard SSL certificate for the server as each app hosted on that server there will be its own subdomain. I would like to set up a test and a prod server (2 servers) using the following domain names (for example): appserver.com and test.appserver.com. As a cost cutting measure, because we don't have the money to spend, I would like to buy a single wildcard cert and use it for both my production and test server (*.appserver.com).

My question is; is this feasible solution and will it work? Has anyone else attempted this approach with SharePoint 2016 or 2019 on prem? Or am I forced to buy 2 wildcard certs?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to purchase a Wildcard cert with a UCC extension, that is `*.appserver.com` and `*.test.appserver.com`.

There may be additional cost to this, you would need to contact your SSL reseller, look into self-signed certificates for testing purposes, or perhaps even the Lets Encrypt service, which is free.